# layer for background package when includepdf is used

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, overlays, backgrounds

For my purpose, I first wish to stay with `background` package if possible.

It works fine when I have texts only. Background is really background (in terms of the layers).

[image]

But when `includepdf` or `\fitallincludepdf` (a modified version) is used to include some pdf files, the background come foreward, which I don't like.

[image]

If you look closely, the `test` is ABOVE the pdf file like an overlay.

How can I make it underneath?

The following is used to make `exam-pic.pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[fitpaper]{example-image-A}
    \includepdf[fitpaper]{example-image-10x16}
\end{document}
```

Now the `MWE`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, scheme=plain, twosides]{ctexart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=6,
    contents={test}
}%


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fitallincludepdf[2][]{%
    \AM@findfile{#2}%
    \setkeys{pdfpages}{#1}%
    \expandafter\AM@readlist\expandafter{\AM@pagestemp}%
    \@for\xxx:=\AM@pagelist\do{%
    \edef\AM@tmp{[\unexpanded{#1},pages=\xxx]}%
    \expandafter\includepdf\AM@tmp{#2}%
}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-10]
\cleardoublepage
\includepdf[pages=-]{exam-pic}
\fitallincludepdf[fitpaper,pages=-]{exam-pic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: example-image has a gray background. If you put your background text in the background it will be behind the gray and so not visible. Would that be ok?

Comment: btw: ctexart it not really the right class for a minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That would be GREAT. In fact, that's exactly what I hope to achieve. The real texts are of more importance and I hope these contents can be on the TOP layer and the background (texts and/or images) be just in the background.

Comment: I thought that you want this, but it won't work. You can not split an included image like this. you need pdf's with a transparent background.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry about the confusion. The image might be a bad example. All I need is that to put the image/pdf on top of the background text...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer in other words, yes, the real pdf file would be transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background packages uses `everypage` and this places its hook so that it will on top of \includepdf. An alternative is to use the eso-pic commands instead of background.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages,tikzducks}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\hspace{-5cm}\tikz[scale=8]\duck;}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to move the \includepdf in the foreground, but this will also affect text inserted with page command which will now be behind the picture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages,lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=25,
    contents={\bfseries Text}
}%

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\lipsum[1-4]}]{example-image}


\makeatletter
\def\AM@AddToShipoutPicture{\AddToShipoutPictureFG*}
\makeatother

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\lipsum[1-4]}]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the late "acceptance" of your answer as I need VPN to access SE from China. Otherwise it's VERY slow and nearly impossbile to visit the site.